# SQL Trying to find total weight

Tags: sql, sql-server

[Table diagram](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iTZxV.png)

[image: Table results]

```
Select soh.DueDate, soh.ShipMethod, p.[Weight]
From SalesLT.SalesOrderHeader soh
JOIN SalesLT.SalesOrderDetail sod on sod.SalesOrderID = soh.SalesOrderID
JOIN SalesLT.Product p on p.ProductID = sod.ProductID
where DatePART(year, soh.DueDate)='2017' and DatePART(month, soh.DueDate)='04' or DatePART(month, soh.DueDate)='07' or DatePART(month, soh.DueDate)='11'
```

Snippet Data result text format:

I am currently stuck on this practice question finding total weight in kg's in specific years. Only getting orders which have an unknown shipping method.

Comment: Please don't edit your question in such a way as to make it meaningless once you receive an answer. It needs to continue to make sense for all future people who view it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I edited your query slightly so that it produces the expected results. You may use this.

```
Select Round(sum(coalesce(p.[Weight],0)),2) As Total_wt
From SalesLT.SalesOrderHeader soh
JOIN SalesLT.SalesOrderDetail sod on sod.SalesOrderID = soh.SalesOrderID
JOIN SalesLT.Product p on p.ProductID = sod.ProductID
where DatePART(year, soh.DueDate)=2017 and DatePART(month, soh.DueDate) IN (04,07,11)
and soh.shipmethod = ‘Unknown';
```

Comment: Two issues, one minor, one major. Minor: DATEPART returns an int, so you should preferably use e.g., `DatePART(year, soh.DueDate)=2017` to avoid implicit conversion. Also, this is not SARGable, meaning it cannot use indexes to get better performance. Major: Orders have quantities of items. You're only summing the weights of each type of item.

Comment: The diagram showing the data structure has been removed in an edit. But in SalesOrderDetail there was a 'quantity' field and the weight was in the Product table. But the OP had the issue and it's up to them to solve anyway. They may also want to consider what unit the weights are in... based on the results (where weights were in thousands), I'm guessing they were in grams not kilograms unless it's a container shipping company. And they also need to determine what to do with NULLs.

Comment: Good point. Edited the Datepart filter above. Also, I edited the query in the question and don’t see the data model diagram anymore so will not make an update on that.

Comment: @seanb - I get that you have some good points. However, since the answer has been accepted I guess it worked for the questioner. Let’s close our discussion on this thread. We can always clarify and discuss more on chat.

Comment: Yeah sorry, it came out harsh. Your answer answered the OP's question and used code based on theirs (it's why I stopped doing my answer - yours answered the fundamental question). However, my comments (other than the implicit conversion/SARGability point) were more for the OP to think about rather than criticism of your answer: if the OP wanted to use the answer as their final answer, it may have had those further issues (which they didn't ask about). I would also point the OP to learn about `GROUP BY` for generalising this approach.

Comment: Hello, I have added back the diagrams. The code by Somy worked so I'm assuming it is right. Does it matter that we do not filter out the NULLS because they will not affect the total weight when we sum right? The only part I could not get the code to work was the " IN (04,07,11)" part so I just left it as my long code.

Comment: Re NULLs. You are correct that NULLs in a SUM are just ignored so `SUM(COALESCE(weight,0))` is effectively equivalent to `SUM(weight)`. However, I meant the point logically. No shipment is going to be 0 weight - even a postcard has some weight. A 'NULL' typically is actually meant to represent *unknown* rather than 0. Some of those unknown weights could be massive but not recorded - the question is what that means for the reliability of your answer. On the other hand, you may know because it's been defined in your circumstance that NULL = negligible weight. But it's a question needing asking.